# Sorting typescript array of accanted strings?

Tags: angular, sorting, typescript

I'm trying to sort my array by group and then identifier fields, which works fine, until one of the strings contains a special character, for example `Á` or `Ű`.

Is there any kind of typescript or ng-2 specific method or sth to solve my problem?

Example sorting method:

```
private someSortingMethod(): void {
        this.sortable= this.sortable.sort((t1: SomeThing, t2: SomeThing): number => {
            if (t1.group < t2.group) return -1;
            if (t1.group > t2.group) return 1;
            if (t1.identifier < t2.identifier) return -1;
            if (t1.identifier > t2.identifier) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your input, what do you expect the output to be, and what is your actual output? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a package on npm that does what you need:

```
var removeDiacritics = require('diacritics').remove;
console.log(removeDiacritics("Iлｔèｒｎåｔïｏｎɑｌíƶａｔï߀ԉ"));
// prints "Internationalizati0n"
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/diacritics